# Flask: как можно просматривать лог, если приложение Flask запущено из другого места?

Tags: python, linux, flask, логирование

Есть приложение, написанное на Flask-е. Если я его запускаю из командной строки (`python3 app.py`), то в консоли видно все, что происходит во фласке: какие запросы приходят, ошибки и ворнинги...

Однако, если приложение запущено из другой сессии или, например, приложение запускается автоматически при загрузке системы, то лог уже не доступен.

На английском стеке нашел вопрос [Display the contents of a log file as it is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35540885/display-the-contents-of-a-log-file-as-it-is-updated), где советуют использовать `frontail`, но ссылку там, при этом, дают на syslog, что, вероятно, не то, что мне нужно. Получается, что мне нужно либо знать путь к логу конкретно Фласка, конкретной сессии, либо искать другое решение.

Что можете посоветовать?

Comment: Обратитесь к документации этого самого "другого места" - там наверняка написано, как ведётся и настраивается логирование вывода в этом "другом месте".

Comment: @andreymal Что вы имеете в виду, говоря "другое место"?

Comment: То же самое, что вы имели в виду, написав "другое место" в заголовке этого вопроса.

Comment: @andreymal, вы меня, наверно, не поняли. Вот, допустим, я запускаю приложение Flask в консоли и выхожу из нее (приложение продолжает работать). Где мне раздобыть лог? Мне это искать в документации на Putty? 

Comment: Если вы закрываете терминал с запущенным в нём процессом, то процесс теряет с ним связь и при попытке записать что-то в stdout или stderr он получит ошибку ввода/вывода и просто прекратит свою работу. Поэтому вы рассказываете что-то невозможное, ну или просто что-то не договариваете.

Answer (score 1):

> Что можете посоветовать?

Здесь есть три возможных варианта решения проблемы. Какой именно Вам придётся использовать - зависит от квалификации программиста, который написал это приложение.

**Профессионал** знает, что для выдачи сообщений об ошибках надо использовать модуль *logging*. Тогда (в зависимости от дистрибутива *Linux* эта команда может несколько отличаться), надо в терминале выполнить команду

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog &
```

Это для убунты. Может быть вариант */var/log/messages* или что-то ещё более экзотическое. Обратите внимание на символ амперсенда в конце строки. Он означает, что  эта команда будет в фоне следить за сислогом, а на консоль будут выводиться все новые записи в сислог.

**Полупрофессионал** который знает, что сообщения об ошибках надо писать в лог, но не знает, как. Чаще всего такие люди изобретают собственный сислог и пишут в него. Этот псевдо сислог, как правило, располагается в рабочем каталоге запущенного приложения. Как определить рабочий каталог приложения, запущенного при загрузке системы - отдельный вопрос. Можно попробовать использовать команду *lsof* - запустив её два раза: до запуска приложения и после с сохранением выдачи в двух файлах. Если после этого сравнить эти два файла командой *meld*, то сразу станут видны открывшиеся файлы.
Нечто вроде:

```
lsof > f1.txt
Запускаем приложение
lsof > f2.txt
meld f1.txt f2.txt
```

**Дилетан** который уверен, что сообщения об ошибках надо выдавать с помощью *print(..)*. Самый тяжёлый случай. Можно попробовать так:

1. Находим, как запускается это приложение. Это может быть в файле *.bashrc* в домашнем каталоге, в файле */etc/rc.local* или какой-то файл в каталоге */etc/systemd*
2. В конец строки запуска приложения дописываем код: *> /tmp/syslog 2>&1* Это приведёт к тому, что все выдачи в *stdoui* и *stderr* будут ложиться в */tmp/syslog*
3. Используем команду слежение за файлом:

   tail -f /tmp/syslog &

Comment: Спасибо за ваши советы! Приложение писал я, а себя я считаю дилетантом в этой части. Выводить ошибки самостоятельно мне в моем случае не требуется. Мне достаточно того лога, который делает Flask сам по себе. Вопрос был лишь в том, как получить доступ к этому логу в том случае, если приложение запускается не мной в консоли.

Comment: @RomanMatveev *достаточно того лога, который делает Flask сам по себе.* - я не спец по Flask, но IMHO, сам по себе он ничего не делает.  Процесс (судя по описанию) развивается так: 1) Запускается интерпретатор  Python. 2) Python читает *.py файл приложения и начинает его выполнять 3) Приложение импортирует Flask и делает вызов *app.run()*   Вот Вам и надо  найти файл, в котором стоит вызов python-а с именем вашего приложения. Где искать - я перечислил в подпункте 1. пункта **дилетант**.

Comment: Если Вы запускаете приложение из другой сесси, то запустите его так, как я сказал в пункте **дилетатн** : *python application.py > /tmp/syslog 2>&1* После этого из любой жругой сесии можете следить за файлом */tmp/syslog*

Answer (score 1):

А ещё фласки в продакшене запускают на gunicorn или совместимый сервер, который, установленный из пакета уже настроен вести лог в journal

`journalctl -u gunicorn -e -f` покажет лог.

Чтоб правильно ответить на Ваш вопрост надо понять как запускается Ваш вэб- сервер.

Пример для системд

```
[Unit]
Description=Flask Server
BindsTo=mysqld.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=www-data
Group=www-data
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 app.py
WorkingDirectory=/opt/path/to/app
Restart=always
RestartSec=30

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Положить в /etc/systemd/system/myflask.service и выполнить

```
systemctl enable myflask
systemctl start myflask
```

Лог будет писаться в журнал и доступен по команде.

```
journalctl -u myflask -e -f
```

где -e -f значит переход в конец и печатать по мере поступления

Comment: Не знаю как и кем запускается веб-сервер (если я правильно понял вас). Apache2 после установки сразу становится автозапускаемым.
Если же говоря "веб-сервер" вы имеете в виду *мое приложение*, то оно запускается из rc.local.

Comment: Сделайте запуск через сервер приложений или через юнит системд - с логом сразу будет всё хорошо. Пример юнита сейчас скину..

Comment: @RomanMatveev добавил инструкции по запуску сервисом с логом